# Is there a tool to help with conflict resolution during MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, conflict

Can I find out if there're good tools available for helping with conflict resolution during the replication process? Specifically MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a replication fault in some way, something's gone wrong.  There's some tools in the Maatkit toolkit that can help out, but in general the easiest and most reliable way to deal with the problem is just to resync (FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; mysqldump --all-databases --master-info; mysql < dumpfile)